# while send an email, send function is not working in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

when I use the following code in my IndexController.php I get the error as displayed below the code:

code in IndexController.php

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action

{

public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{

    $config = array
    (
        'auth' => 'login',
        'username' => 'mymail@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'mypass',
        'ssl' => 'ssl',
        'port' => 465,
    );


    $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);

    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->addTo('othermail@gmail.com', 'me' )
         ->setFrom('mymail@gmail.com', 'me')
         ->setSubject('your trial at fitness first')
         ->setBodyText('email body in plain text')
         ->send($transport);
}
```

}

Error displayed on the page :

```
An error occurred

Application error
```

I never edited any other files just installed zend and created a new project and went  on as the tutorial said ...

But I'm stuck @ the above error

Comment: Damn at that "error". It wouldn't help anything.

Comment: is there any method to debug this officially without repeated trials

Comment: Rather than posting another question covering the same ground as your [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508888/zend-framework-zend-mail-function-error-included-code), it would have been better to edit that question to add the extra information.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly complicated to explain, but I try.

When an error happens in ZF, normally an Exception is thrown. This kicks in your ErrorController.

In that ErrorController you only get the stack trace and an error message when you specified

```
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

in `application/configs/application.ini` for your currently used `APPLICATION_ENV`

Take a look at: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.quick-start.html there it is described how it works.
An easy way to set your APPLICATION_ENV is put this in your `.htaccess` file

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

It's all described in the link.
Then edit your `application/configs/application.ini` like:

```
[development]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gmail, try to change the config to:

```
$config = array
    (
        'auth' => 'login',
        'username' => 'mymail@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'mypass',
        'ssl' => 'tls',
        'port' => 587,
    );
```

If it works, the problem of your previous version should be that openssl is not enabled in your php.ini file